# Reading nothing from the controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been given this task. Basically there is a controller called `DishDetailedController` having an object called `dish`. And there is also a nested controller called `DishCommentContoller` where the user sends a comment through a form. So the first task is to read through all the objects of the `DishDetailedController` and display them in the browser. I will display the comments array objects in another div at a later stage. I did something similar before which was working, but I don't know what is happening now.

https://jsfiddle.net/m8nwnc8a/4/

**Bootstrap Code**

```
<div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                             ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                        <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                    <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJs Code**

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('confusionApp', [])


    .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

        $scope.dish = dish;

    }])

    .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form

        $scope.submitComment = function () {

            //Step 2: This is how you record the date
            "The date property of your JavaScript object holding the comment" = new Date().toISOString();

            // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
            $scope.dish.comments.push("Your JavaScript Object holding the comment");

            //Step 4: reset your form to pristine

            //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
        }
    }]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't include jQuery file in jsFiddle. Is this the case in actual code as well???

Comment: Whaaaa?? `"The date property of your JavaScript object holding the comment" = new Date().toISOString();`

Comment: @Alon Eitan. Dear God,I didn't comment that out...Thanks.

Comment: @Theo But does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Alon Eitan. Yeap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to include a lot of things, from `ng-app`. `ng-controller` to script files.

This should work:
https://jsfiddle.net/m8nwnc8a/28/

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not initiating your angular app.
You are missing the ng-app and ng-controller sections.
Also, some HTML tags are not closed properly.

I have fixed them.

[Working demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RXAy5dkVERSJQoZrTyer)

Code :

```
<body ng-app="confusionApp">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="DishDetailController">

        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#"><img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{ dish.image }} alt="Uthappizza"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{ dish.name }}</h2>
                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                        <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
```